# Dimension of null space

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the linear transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ such that $T(x_1,x_2)=(x_1-x_2, x_2-x_1, -x_1)$. Find dimension of null space.

Now in this question, I find that the only member of the null space is the zero vector. So the dimension should be $1$. But the answer is $0$. Why is it so ?

Comment: The dimension of the zero space is zero, not one.

Comment: How did you find that out

Comment: Dear Ka Sikh, since you are rather new to SE I would like to remind you that mathematical expressions should be written with the help of the MathJax software to ensure readability of your questions :)

Comment: By definition of dimension. The dimension of a vector space is defined as the number of elements in a basis. By definition, the set $\left\{0\right\}$ is not linearly independent (Indeed, $5\cdot 0=0$ is a non-trivial linear combination of the vectors in $\left\{0\right\}$ that is zero), hence it's not a basis of the zero space. In fact the zero space is generated by a basis with no elements.

Answer (score 1):

The subspace consisting of *only* the zero vector, has dimension $0$.

Take a look at "[Why $\mathbf{0}$ vector has dimension zero?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664594/why-mathbf0-vector-has-dimension-zero)" for more details, but note that in this question/title, it should be the "*subspace $\left\{ {\bf 0} \right\}$*" rather than only the "*element ${\bf 0}$*".

---

> Now in this question, I find that the only member of the null space is the zero vector. So the dimension should be $1$. But the answer is $0$. Why is it so ?

If the dimension would be $1$, any basis for this subspace would consist of exactly **one** (non-zero) vector (by the definition of dimension), since a basis has to be linearly independent. But then the subspace spanned by this basis necessarily has an *infinite number* of elements, since all scalar multiples of the basis vector are in the subspace.